# What inequalities involving $D, E,$ and $F$ in a general form of a circle, $x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ such that $d > 0$ in $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=d$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, circles

What inequalities involving $D, E,$ and $F$ in a general form of a circle, $x^2+y^2+Dx+Ey+F=0,$ such that $d>0$ in $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=d$?

need help please explain

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$x^2 +y^2 +Dx +Ey +F = \left( x-\left(-\frac{D}{2}\right)\right)^2 +\left( y-\left(-\frac{E}{2}\right)\right)^2 -\left(-\frac{D}{2}\right)^2 -\left(-\frac{E}{2}\right)^2 +F$$ so if the equation $$x^2 +y^2 +Dx +Ey +F =0$$
represents a circle then $$F-\frac{D^2}{4} -\frac{E^2}{4} <0.$$

Comment: im sorry im not great at math, where did u get the (x-(-d/2)^2 and the (y-(-e/2))^2? and the others?